# Assembly forward reference needs override error

Tags: assembly, x86, stopwatch, tasm

Using TASM, I have successfully programmed a digital stopwatch (LAP and normal) on emu8086 but when I try to run it on TASM i get the error `Forward reference needs override`. I know why this error occurs as I have two procedures both including a `call` of the other procedure so putting one of the procedure before the other one won't work. For example

```
proc1 proc
;some code
CALL proc2
;some code
ret
endp

proc2 proc
;some code
CALL proc1
;some code
ret
endp
```

Another solution would be defining/writing the whole procedure instead of calling it but that gives an error of `Relative jump out of range`. (My code has several jumps too)

My Question is that is there anyway I can remove the `forward reference needs override` error in my situation?

Comment: I'm curious, is there a specific reason you're using TASM? Its latest version was released in 1996, that's 17 years ago!

Comment: @us2012 yes there is. Anyways is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Appartently yes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other sources seem to suggest that TASM has a multi-pass command line option `/m2`, which will do the specified number of passes over the source. Two passes should be sufficient in your case, as the first pass will see the definition of `proc2` and the second pass can then use it to correctly translate the earlier `call proc2`.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how? I haven't read about /m2 yet. Would be a great help

Comment: @worriednacho When at the moment you type `tasm.exe myfile.asm` to assemble your source code, simply put `tasm.exe /m2 myfile.asm` instead. Or are you asking for a more detailed explanation on how a second pass will solve the problem?